# Data transformation in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have a filed value like "+000002030" need to convert it to "20.30" how can i do this using XSLT. This value "+000002030" is the dynamic one any value it can come.Please let me know how we can convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(translate(value, '+', '') div 100, '#.00')"/>
```

---

To make this future-proof, use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number(translate(value, '+', '')) div 100, '#.00')"/>
```

This will work the same in both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in XSLT-2.0 would be

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(number('+000002030') div 100, '#.00')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working fine . Getting the response as expected. Thanks for your support